# How to check the Datetime between the Datetime columns

Tags: sql

How to check the Datetime between the Datetime columns?

For example:

```
Column1             Column2         Price
------------------------------------------
01/05/2019          31/06/2019        50
01/07/2019          31/09/2019        49
01/10/2019          31/12/2019        48
01/01/2020          31/01/2020        45
```

Now, how can I send Price based on dates?

If today date is 01/06/2019 then we will send the price as 50 or today's date is 25/01/2020 then we will send 45 like that.

How can I do this query?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Column data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
SELECT Price FROM [TableName] WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN Column1 AND Column2
```

As long as the Date columns do not overlap and reflect 1 price for each given period.

SQL Compliance

In Oracle use CURRENT_DATE instead of GETDATE()